# Tkinter have code for pages in separate files

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have code that opens up a window and has three buttons for page 1, page 2, and page 3. However I also have four .py files (Dashboard, PageOne, PageTwo. PageThree). Dashboard will be the file that used to run the application. I want it so that the code from each file is only runs/displayed when the user clicks on the corresponding page button.

Dashboard.py:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import PageOne
import PageTwo
import PageThree

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)
        p3 = Page3(self)

        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p3.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 1", command=p1.lift)
        b2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 2", command=p2.lift)
        b3 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 3", command=p3.lift)

        b1.pack(side="left")
        b2.pack(side="left")
        b3.pack(side="left")

        p1.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("400x400")
    root.mainloop()
```

PageOne.py:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import Dashboard

class Page1(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

PageTwo.py

```
import Tkinter as tk
import Dashboard

class Page2(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

PageThree.py:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import Dashboard

class Page3(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 3")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ross.watson\Google Drive\Smart Mirror\Test\Dashboard.py", line 2, in <module>
    import PageOne
  File "C:\Users\ross.watson\Google Drive\Smart Mirror\Test\PageOne.py", line 2, in <module>
    import Dashboard
  File "C:\Users\ross.watson\Google Drive\Smart Mirror\Test\Dashboard.py", line 3, in <module>
    import PageTwo
  File "C:\Users\ross.watson\Google Drive\Smart Mirror\Test\PageTwo.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Page2(Page):
NameError: name 'Page' is not defined
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are getting at but is the answer as simple as placing each page inside a separate file (e.g. page1.py) and using 'from page1 import Page1' ?

Comment: @scotty3785 When I cut `class Page3(Page):` in `PageThree.py` I get `NameError: global name 'Page1' is not defined` when running `Dashboard.py`

Comment: Might be helpful if you post what you have tried. How did you try to import the PageX class from its module?

Comment: @scotty3785 I've edited my question, hopefully that makes it clearer what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Place the class Page in it's own file Page.py and use 'from Page import Page' in each of the PageX.py files.

Comment: Also inside Dashboard.py you need to use

    p1 = PageOne.Page1(self)

to initialise the page class.

Comment: Also if you are trying to re-create a tabbed notebook effect, then you should probably just use the built in ttk.Notebook. 
The .lift method is designed to bring windows to the front not frame widgets

Comment: @scotty3785 Thank you that worked. Ah I will look into ttk Notebook. Thanks again

Comment: `class page_1(give_me_some_subclass)` otherwise can't access `GUI`resource. Build with instantiation, don't call A in B or B in A. `From A import A` is wrong, `from a import *` suppressed all duplicate names

Comment: @scotty3785: _" The .lift method is designed to bring windows to the front not frame widgets "_ is not a true statement. The `lift` command absolutely is designed to change the stacking order of _all_ widgets. However, your advice to use the ttk notebook is good.

Comment: Ross: Why haven't you never accepted @Bryan's answer?

Answer (score 7):

The error messages tell you everything you need to know in order to fix the problem. This is a simple problem that has nothing to do with tkinter, and everything to do with properly organizing and using your code.

For example, what is `Page is not defined` telling you? It's telling you, quite literally, that `Page` is not defined. You defined it in your main file, but you're using it in another file. The solution is to move the definition of `Page` to a separate file that can be imported into the files that use it.

Modify your files and imports to look like this:

### page.py

```
class Page(tk.Frame):
    ...
```

### pageOne.py

```
from page import Page
class PageOne(Page):
    ...
```

### pageTwo.py

```
from page import Page
class PageTwo(Page):
    ...
```

### pageThree.py

```
from page import Page
class PageThree(Page):
    ...
```

### Dashboard.py

```
from pageOne import PageOne
from pageTwo import PageTwo
from pageThree import PageThree
...
```