# How to link classes in different python files (Multiple Frame)? Link Different Pages back to MenuPage?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm new to python, hopefully can get some advise or right approach to solve this.
I intended to create multiple frame in GUI, it works perfectly when i composed all classes in one python file, then I separated classes(Frame) into different file. Unfortunately, I could not link back to my **MenuPage** because of no reference in that particular python file(I tried to call **MenuPage** and it shows error after compile)... Maybe I was not familiar with the class call method...
A main class created as below:

```
from tkinter import*
from GSOPage import*
class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, MenuPage, GSOPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(MenuPage)
    def show_frame(self, context):
        frame = self.frames[context]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

class MenuPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        GSO = PhotoImage(file='GSOMenu.png')
        GSOM = Button(self, image=GSO, command=lambda: GSOAct())
        GSOM.image = GSO
        GSOM.place(x=-2,y=-2)
        def GSOAct():
            controller.show_frame(GSOPage)
...
```

Subclass : GSOPage

```
from tkinter import*
from GSOExp import*
class GSOPage(Frame):
   ...
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        ...
        Back = PhotoImage(file="GSOBack.png")
        BackBtn = Button(self, image=Back, bd=0, bg='black', command=lambda: BackAct())
        BackBtn.image = Back
        BackBtn.place(x=0, y=0)
        def BackAct():
            controller.show_frame(MenuPage)
```

When I pressed *BackBtn* in GUI, it shows the error as below:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jun Hong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Jun Hong\PycharmProjects\Tutorial\Calculator\GSOPage.py", line 18, in <lambda>
    BackBtn = Button(self, image=Back, bd=0, bg='black', command=lambda: BackAct())
  File "C:\Users\Jun Hong\PycharmProjects\Tutorial\Calculator\GSOPage.py", line 426, in BackAct
    controller.show_frame(MenuPage)
NameError: name 'MenuPage' is not defined
```

In conclusion, how can I link GSOPage back to MenuPage(defined in main class)

Thanks for help...

Comment: That leads to circular imports, consider to use string `"MenuPage"` instead of `class MenuPage`. This requires to extend `controller.show_frame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguably the best solution is to not require you use the actual class. Instead, store the pages by class *name*. By doing so, you don't need to import every page into every other page.

For example, change the loop that makes the pages to look like this:

```
for F in (StartPage, MenuPage, GSOPage):
    page_name = F.__name__
    frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
    self.frames[page_name] = frame
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

Next, modify `show_page` to accept a name rather than a class:

```
def show_frame(self, page_name):
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.tkraise()
```

With that, from any file you can request a page with the name, and without having to import the page:

```
controller.show_frame("MenuPage")
```

---

Another solution would be to move the definition of `Page` to its own file, so that you don't have to import the main program in each of your pages.

That solution is described in a bit more detail here: [Tkinter have code for pages in separate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39530107/tkinter-have-code-for-pages-in-separate-files)